# In which should I let my gears when not biking?

Tags: gears

I heard from a friend I shouldn't let my bike "resting" with the combination biggest front ring and the smallest back ring because in his words "it keeps the system under tension".

Does it make sense?
How should I let the gears?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this has been asked before but I cna't find it. :-(

Comment: Me neither :-)))

Comment: In theory, if you leave the gears in small/small you will extend the life of the rear derailer tension spring (which has a normal life of maybe 50 years) by maybe 1%.  Of course, leaving it at that bad chain angle will not do nice things for other components, nor is the wear of getting into and out of that position helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry about it, it really doesn't matter what gear you leave it in.

Can't comment so, this is a duplicate of [this](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/31694/when-not-used-what-gear-should-i-store-my-bike-in).